# Low rank approximation of a matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Consider a $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\Sigma\mathbf{V}^T$. Also assume that all the entries of $\mathbf{A}$ are positive i-e $a_{ij}>0 \hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{2mm} 1\leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq m$.

My question is can we say some definite about the sign of entries of its rank-r approximation $\mathbf{A_r}$

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A_r}=\mathbf{U_r}\Sigma_r\mathbf{V_r^T}
\end{equation}

where

1. $\mathbf{U_r}\rightarrow$ first *r left singular vectors*
2. $\Sigma_r\rightarrow$ diagonal matrix of first *r-singular vaules*
3. $\mathbf{V_r}\rightarrow$ first *r right singular vectors*

In other words, if we start from a non-negative matrix $\mathbf{A}$ then its SVD will also be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Try e.g. the rank-$2$ approximation of

$$ \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr} $$

EDIT: (for an example with nonnegative entries).  If you want strictly positive entries, change $0$ to  $\epsilon > 0$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$: $\epsilon = 0.1$ will do.

Comment: I think it also works with $M_{2,2}=0$.

Comment: Simple example clarifies ..... one more question. For such $\mathbf{A}$, how about using non-negative matrix factorization (nnmf) [W,H]=nnmf(A,k) http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nnmf.html . What do we loose with nnmf. One thing obvious to me is the iterative process of finding W,H can get struck in local minima....would you like to point out anything else?

Comment: The entries are not all positive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with nnmf.

Comment: @AlexSilva So change the $0$'s to $\epsilon$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I agree, but I think you should edit your answer, since the question and the answer mismatch.

Comment: @anderstood What do you mean?  With $A_{2,2}$ changed to $0$ in my example, the matrix would already have rank $2$, and the rank-$2$ approximation would be the matrix itself.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah OK, I thought the rank-$2$ approximation was a 2 by 2 matrix.